# How to use Vue instance data in components?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I defined some data in a [vuejs](/questions/tagged/vuejs) instance, but when I use the data, I receive this message:

> Property or method "url" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.

This is where the data is located:

```
Vue.component('app-dashboard', require('./components/AppDashboard.vue'));
Vue.component('header-top', require('./components/Header.vue'));
Vue.component('navbox', require('./components/Navbox.vue'));
Vue.component(Vodal.name, Vodal);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      url: {
        dashboard: laroute.route('dashboard'),
        request: laroute.route('requests.get'),
        send: laroute.route('requests.send'),
        history: laroute.route('history'),
        userAll: laroute.route('users.all')
      }
    }
});
```

This is how I use the data in my component:

```
// Header.vue
    <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" :href="url.dashboard">Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" :href="url.request">File Request</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" :href="url.send">Send Files</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" :href="url.history">History</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" :href="url.userAll">User Management</a>
        </li>
```

Comment: Use Vuex. Its far better than props, cleaner, more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vue, children do not have access to their parent's data directly, you need to pass it down as a property.

In your Header.vue component you should define a property called `url`

```
export default {
  props:["url"],
  ...
}
```

and pass the value in the parent's template.

```
<header-top :url="url"></header-top>
```

The Vue documentation is excellent. You should read through [component composition](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components).